# "Ideal" Java Development Setup for OS X Mavericks?

Tags: java, installation

I've been using Ruby for a long time, and while there is no "one true setup" for Ruby development, there are common patterns, eg:

- Install a ruby version manager (rvm, rbenv)
- Install ruby gems to manage ruby libraries
- Choose a text editor (TextMate, Sublime, vim, etc)

I am getting started with Java now, and I am wondering if there is a similar "ideal" path to setting up a good Java development environment.

Edit:

In Ruby development, there are certain problems that need to be addressed in order to have a reasonably "sane" development environment, eg:

- management of Ruby versions (so that you can work on older and newer projects in the same environment)
- Ruby library management, particularly isolating different versions of installed libraries from each other
- choosing an IDE
- etc

I am moving into Java development on OSX now, and I would like to know what the Java development "pain points" are, and various solutions for managing them.

Answer (score 2):

Install JDK+JRE 8, Gradle for package management (or Maven, you can install both).
You can use IntelliJ (licensed, needs JDK 6 on OS X) , NetBeans or Eclipse as IDE

Comment: Thank you.  How is Java versioning managed, through the IDE?

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean with versioning managed ? Are you talking about Java compiler version ? If your Java project use Gradle, it's defined in build.gradle, if you use Maven it's defined in pom.xml, on simple Java project it's defined on the IDE and at build time it will call the correct java compiler

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Java world.

Mac OS X comes with JDK preinstalled. You can go to console and type java -version to find more details on version and provider etc.

Default Installed location (Version may be different on different OSX version):

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

If you install new version of JDK from Oracle(Sun), it will get installed to following location.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In order to switch between versions you can set JAVA_HOME in profile.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Now you have multiple versions of JDK to play with, Download eclipse or any other IDE and start rocking. You need [maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/installation) as build tool, install them too.

Once you installed all of the above, then [follow IDE](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/39279/create-a-new-maven-project-in-eclipse/) to start first hello world project.

If it makes it easier to see a sample project, please take a look at [simplest maven project I have](https://github.com/kamoor/algorithm-samples). Just clone and run "mvn clean install"

Good luck